# Thermador oven circuit board troubleshooting - where to go from here?

Tags: relay, temperature, troubleshooting, board

I have a Thermador double oven unit that is not working correctly in one of its cooking modes. I have done some troubleshooting, but haven’t located the problem to my satisfaction. I wanted to see if there were any suggestions as to where I could go next.

Here is the issue:

The unit has one control board and one relay board for each oven. The upper oven is malfunctioning and the lower oven is working fine on all settings. The upper oven has three settings (and three separate elements): bake, broil and convection. The broil and convection settings seem to work fine, but the bake setting will not bring the oven up to temperature.

The bake cycle runs a program that runs a 60 second cycle where the bake element is on for 51 seconds and the broil element is on for 8 (see pic). The bake element side of the circuit seems to be at fault as it does not ever heat up enough to glow. I have tested all elements, and they check out for ohms within specification. I have tested the harnesses and the wires are intact (continuity test with a multimeter.) I was fairly certain that the relay that energizes the bake element was at fault, but I have had the board out and tested both the bake and broil relays by applying DC power to the coil sides of the relays and testing for continuity at the other contacts and they check out. As for the board itself there are no obvious burned areas or bad components (see attached.)

With the oven running and the panel open the bake relay, which was suspect, does not always seem to be closing or opening in the correct sequence. Similarly with the oven in diagnostic mode, the bake relay does not seem to be operating.

Could the relay be bad in spite of checking out on the bench?

Should I look at testing other components and how?

Can anyone think of where I might go to test from here? Is there an easy way to move upstream and test that the control board is sending the correct signals to the relay board?

Any help would be appreciated, I am a newbie at this, but I am looking for an excuse to learn to solder.

[image: relay board]

[image: Wiring Diagram]

[image: Bake cycle]

[image: relay board diagram]

Comment: This forum is not for electronics repair. I have read very quickly and not detailed, but - change the relays.

Comment: Continuity usually means "less than 200 ohms."  There's no standard for it, but many meters use that value.  Use multimeter as an ohmmeter, and measure resistance rather than continuity.  The relay contacts, for example, could show continuity but still have such high resistance that the heating coils can't get hot.

Comment: Repair questions are not explicitly off topic, but we need more than "Here is what I have, help me fix it" It should be a subset problem like (how do I replace this transistor, or help me fix this circuit) https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/is-asking-on-how-to-fix-a-faulty-circuit-on-topic

Comment: Thanks for the info/feedback, I appreciate it. I looked at some repair forums and the answers i saw others get there were often too basic. I thought the information I got here would be more useful. I suppose the question should have been "Is there a better way to test this circuit?" or "How can test signaling from a control board to isolate a relay?"  Resistance across the closed relays was about 4 miliohms.

Answer (score 1):

The board isn't really a repair forum. But from an electronic design standpoint, when large components like relays are attached to a PCB, a potential weak spot is created due to thermal cycling, vibration, etc. An intermittent open circuit can be hard to diagnose because when you remove the board, you change the stresses on the component and PCB.  So carefully inspect the solder joints of the bake relay for cracks. Or, just resolder them by adding flux a little fresh solder while reheating them. They solder should be shiny and concave between the pin and the PCB trace. Also inspect the PCB traces using a bright light behind the board. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Mark, I think you're right. I recall that the relay seemed to be operating correctly when the oven was cold, but that as it heated up relay seemed to work less and less. Earlier today, when the oven was hot, it didn't wasn't working at all. Maybe as the temp comes up there is enough heat in the board compartment to interrupt the circuit at a cracked solder joint. Still, I wish there was a way to test the control board to totally isolate the relay as the failure point. I'm either taking this apart and mailing it out for a repair or learning to solder and I'd rather learn to solder.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you ever figuered this out, but I am having a similar issue. I assume the picture of the board you showed is the board you took out of your oven. There is a burned area on your board.

Comment: I did actually:

It was the relay (K1 from the diagram above). Seems like a common issue. It's been a little while, so I don't recall exactly, but I ended up reconnecting the board, and running the cycle while testing the circuits with a multimeter. It was probably a little dangerous, but it made me 100% sure of the fault. 

Unfortunately, my soldering skills weren't up to the task and I cooked one of the traces right off the board. Been limping by on the other oven functions/lower oven since, but have plans to have it professionally repaired at some point.

Good luck with your issue.

Comment: Oh, and as for the burns: I did notice that, but it didn't seem to be causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tested the board during cycle through the wiring harness and along individual traces and found the relay (Bake - K1) to be at fault.